# Row highlight fails with Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, cross-browser, bootstrap-5

The goal of this code is to highlight one row when clicked/tapped and show an offcanvas area with some buttons. It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome (at least on Android) after playing a bit it ends with two rows selected. Tap to select a row > offcanvas is shown > tap again > offcancas is hidden. After several times, two rows are selected at the same time.

It's not related on how fast you tap... but after some time it happens.

Is there any fault in my code?

```js
let index = 1;

document.querySelector('#table').onclick = function(e) {
  index = e.target.parentElement.rowIndex;
  let row = e.target.parentElement;

  if (index > 0) {
    row.classList.add('table-active');
    let offcanvas = document.getElementById("offcanvasEdit");
    let bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(offcanvas);
    bsOffcanvas.show();

    let siblingRow = row.parentNode.firstChild;
    while (siblingRow) {
      if (siblingRow.nodeType === 1 && siblingRow !== row) siblingRow.classList.remove('table-active');
      siblingRow = siblingRow.nextSibling;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="table" class="table table-sm table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">A</th>
      <th scope="col">B</th>
      <th scope="col">C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-group-divider">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
      </td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='' disabled='disabled'>
      </td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasEdit" aria-labelledby="offcanvasEditLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasEditLabel">Tools</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    <div class="d-grid gap-2 mx-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Edit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap v5.3.1

### UPDATE

I've just discovered that with the new snippet is more easy to replicate the issue. I added some input checkbox in the table.
Now if you tap on the cell with the checkbox the highlight is duplicated:

[image]

Comment: Not sure why all the comments were deleted (mine also). Anyway, I found the cause was the class `table-hover`. As a temporary workaround I removed it. The question is still valid, in my opinion.